# How to change pull location on Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, repository

I use mercirual and I cloned a remote repository. It created a new folder an inside it the **.hg** folder. But now when I enter hg pull in the command line, it says the `.hg` folder is not found inside Mercurial folder (that's because the clone function created another folder first).

How do I deal with that? Is there a way to change the `pull` location?

Answer (score 1):

err what? You usually are not supposed to manually modify the contents of the .hg folder with the exception of .hg/hgrc.

However, the repo's config file has a section which allows to set the pull and push location(s):

```
[paths]
default = path_or_URL/to/default/repo
othername = path/to/other/repo
pushurl = path_or_URL/to/default/repo/to/push/to
```

In the setup as above, the default pull and push should be clear, and there's another name defined, `othername`, which you can also simply refer to in commands which require a repo name. For instance you can push to it by using:

```
hg push othername
```

Check out `hg help config` for more details.

Comment: 1) `default-pull` key doesn't exist. `default-push` is *deprecated* (but still can be used) and [replaced by `pushurl` sub-option](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I corrected my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I got this right: You did `hg clone ssh://example.com/some/project`, and it created a folder `project`, right?

You don't need to change the pull path, it's set correctly. What you need to do is type

```
cd project
```

Then you'll be inside your project folder, and you'll be able to use mercurial commands the way you expect.